# How do I allow the overwriting of blobs from my ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

Users can upload images when a record is created, when you edit that record and try to upload new images there is an error of "This blob already exists".  Is there a way that I can enable the overwriting of blobs with the same name in my application?

Here is my code that handles the update process.

> It's important to note that I create three iterations of an image for
>   the sake of the application so I have included the array that has that
>   information.

**CarController.cs**

```
private readonly int[] sizeArray = new int[] { 700, 350, 150 };

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(Car car)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Create the Car
                _carService.InsertCar(car);

                //Get the ID of the newly created car
                int id = car.Id;

                //Define the container name for Azure Storage
                string strContainerName = "uploads";                               

                //Blob Client
                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(accessKey);
                BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(strContainerName);

                //Iterate over the array of image sizes
                foreach (var imageSize in sizeArray)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Pass image to image processor and save to the blob location
                        string fileName = "car/" + id + "/car-image-" + imageSize + ".jpg";
                        Stream returnStream = ProcessImage(imageSize, car);
                        containerClient.UploadBlob(fileName, returnStream);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }                   
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }            
            return View(car);
        }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you're using [v12 client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet).

Then there is no blob overwriting method in **container** level, you should use `Upload(Stream content, bool overwrite = false)` method of the `BlobClient`. Sample code like below:

```
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(mycontainer);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("blob_name");

            blobClient.Upload(your_stream, overwrite: true);
```

Comment: This solution was perfect, thank you for this.  I had read about the overwrite but wasn't sure I could use it.  Awesome.

Comment: There does not seem to be an overload for Upload that accepts both the boolean overwrite parameter and the BlobUploadOptions (to set metadata).  Am I missing something?

Comment: Works well with 12.12.0

Comment: UploadAsync function overload which takes BlobUploadOptions overwrites the blob. You've to set condition in options if you wish to not overwrite.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.upload?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobclient-upload(system-io-stream-azure-storage-blobs-models-blobuploadoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)

Answer (score 22):

If you want to specify both `overwrite: true` and use `BlobStorageOptions` at the same time, this is the implementation of the `Upload(...)` overload with the `bool overwrite` parameter:

```cs
public virtual Response<BlobContentInfo> Upload(
    Stream content,
    bool overwrite = false,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) =>
    Upload(
        content,
        conditions: overwrite ? null : new BlobRequestConditions { IfNoneMatch = new ETag(Constants.Wildcard) },
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Which leads to the following overload (some code omitted for brevity):

```cs
public virtual Response<BlobContentInfo> Upload(
    ....
    BlobRequestConditions conditions = default,
    ....) =>
    StagedUploadInternal(
        content,
        new BlobUploadOptions
        {
            ...
            Conditions = conditions,
            ...
        },
        ...
```

So actually `overwrite` is the default as soon as you specify your own `BlobUploadOptions` without any specific `IfNoneMatch` option.

This is also supported by the comments on the function:

```
// Summary:
//     The Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobClient.UploadAsync(System.IO.Stream,Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobUploadOptions,System.Threading.CancellationToken)
//     operation overwrites the contents of the blob, creating a new block blob if none
//     exists. Overwriting an existing block blob replaces any existing metadata on
//     the blob. Set access conditions through Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobUploadOptions.Conditions
//     to avoid overwriting existing data.
```

Code copied from [`BlobClient.cs`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/800851eaad8f9a4a7ef0cf12c4fa764748304559/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/src/BlobClient.cs#L780).

Comment: Thank you!; this answer solved my problem, with a little adjustment: In the `v12.13.1` of the `Azure.Storage.Blobs`, the `Constants.Wildcard` does not exist anymore, so I needed to use the wildcard (i.e. '*') directly: `new ETag("*")`

Answer (score -2):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet) states:

> For partial block blob updates and other advanced features, please see
>   BlockBlobClient. To create or modify page or append blobs, please see
>   PageBlobClient or AppendBlobClient.

You should therefore probably use a [BlockBlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) or something that is updateable.