# Azure Blob Overwrite

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, httpclient

When I try to upload a file to azure blob and this file already exists, I get 403 status code that the request is forbiden and the message is

> This request is not authorized to perform blob overwrites.

inspite of having contributor and Storage Blob Data Contributor roles assigned to me, the code I use to perform the request is a simple HttpClient put request and the blob type is BlockBlob

```
await Client.PutAsync(fileMetadata.DirectUploadUrl, content);
```

Comment: Hi, have a look at this thread ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61081233/how-do-i-allow-the-overwriting-of-blobs-from-my-asp-net-core-application) it may help you

Comment: I am using HttpClient not BlobVlient, and unfortunately can't change the HttpClient

Comment: And how is the authentication configured?

Comment: Can you provide the "Storage Account Contributor" access and check for the status   
 Can you provide the latest request ID, in this scenario auth is causing  issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the request was using SAS token which includes the permissions associated with the request, so I added the write permission to the URL

> sp=rcw

according to this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas?redirectedfrom=MSDN